# How to parse date format in java?

Tags: java

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-01-15 00:003:00" ecxception is throwing
please shorout my peoblem
Thanks
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Dd {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

String s1="2014-01-15 00:003:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy--MM-dd h:mm:ss");
   try{

Date date =sdf.parse(s1);
      SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd--MMM-dd H:mm:ss"); 
      String s3=sdf1.format(date);
System.out.println(s3);

 }
   catch (ParseException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: You can find lot of answers in stackoverflow it self.

Comment: Lots of answer for this question. Duplicate question.

Comment: dear can u solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
String s1 = "2013-01-15 8:00:03";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dt=sdf.parse(s1);//converting to date
         SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss");
         String s2=sdf1.format(dt);//formating to new format string
         System.out.println(s2);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }
```

//new answer

```
public class Dd {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        String s1 = "2014-01-15 00:003:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(s1);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String s3 = sdf1.format(date);
            System.out.println(s3);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: is throwing

Comment: have you add these imports..
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

Comment: i have import all package

Comment: can yon check my code

Comment: public class Dd {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {String s1="2014-01-15 00:003:00";                           SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy--MM-dd h:mm:ss");
   try{Date date =sdf.parse(s1);
      SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd--MMM-dd H:mm:ss"); 
      String s3=sdf1.format(date);
System.out.println(s3);                                          }
   catch (ParseException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
  }

Comment: sir i have edited my question u can find out my problem from there

Comment: you can check out my new answer below the first one.. and see the difference between my code and yours.. you have put some extra "-" in youtr date formats

Comment: i am getting this output 15-Jan-15 12:03:00   and my desired output is 15-jan-2014 12:03:00

Comment: sorry mistake from my side you can check it out now.. i have changed the date format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The following pattern letters are defined (all other characters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```